# (!var) vs (var==null) in java / groovy

Tags: java, performance, groovy, null

What is recommended in `java`  :

```
if(!var){

}
```

or

```
 if(var==null){

}
```

and why?

It is the same thing with `Groovy`?

Comment: if `var` is not `boolean`, then `if(!var)` is not valid in Java

Comment: IMHO There is no relation between this two in java...if you are following some coding standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java, if `var` is `null`,

```
if( !var ) {
    // var is not null
}
```

Won't work as `!` is for booleans.

In Groovy, it will work as it applies Groovy Truth.

HOWEVER, if you are testing for `null`, then you should use the explicit test

```
if( var != null ) {
    // var is not null
}
```

Even in Groovy, as if var was anything Groovy considers `false`, the first comparison would pass, ie:

```
assert !0
assert !''
assert ![]
assert !null
```

Of course you can also use the null safe operator:

```
def map = [ person:[ tim:[ login:'tim_yates' ] ] ]

assert map?.person?.tim?.login == 'tim_yates'
assert map?.person?.alice?.login == null
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one in Java would apply only to booleans

Answer (score 2):

The unary operator `!` does the negation operation. For example,
`!false` will yield `true`.

And `==` does comparison operation.

They both are completely different to each other. In java, you can use the negation operator only with `boolean` values, whereas the comparison operator can be used to compare values.

Also, in Java, if `var` is `Boolean` and is `null`, then

```
if(!var){ // would throw a NullPointerException
}
```